# Can't commit files from origin/<name> to origin/master

Tags: git

While pushing some fixes to the master branch I accidentally created a new branch origin/<name> and it got uploaded and git showed **branch name** was just created.
When I execute `$ git show-ref`

The output is:

```
57c425c922d25ebb90c0acdb824f103eb5086188 refs/heads/master
57c425c922d25ebb90c0acdb824f103eb5086188 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
57c425c922d25ebb90c0acdb824f103eb5086188 refs/remotes/origin/master
aeb2652a82d0d95af940d42007e4315621f7e4d1 refs/remotes/origin/ron
```

My codes didn't merge with **origin/master**.
How can I clean this up? And working with a new local branch and commit all those changes to the master branch in the repository

Comment: you can create a pull request to `origin/branch name` and merge it to `origin/master`

Comment: how to delete the newly created origin/<name> branch?

Comment: delete local branch `$ git branch -D branch_name` and delete remote branch using remote `git push origin --delete <your_branch>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a terminology issue you should deal with first, because otherwise everything's going to be horribly confusing:

- A name like `master` is a *branch name*.
- A name like `origin/master` is a *remote-tracking name*, or sometimes—well, more typically, really—called a *remote-tracking branch name*.  I don't like this phrase, because these remote-tracking things do not work enough like (local) branch names, and it's too easy to confuse the two.

These both exist inside your own Git repository, but the remote-tracking names exist ***because of*** some *other* Git repository:

- `origin`, by itself, is a *remote*.  A remote is just a short name that represents some other Git repository, and stores a URL by which *your* Git can call up that *other* Git.

With all of that in mind, there's a sort of secret, which is important, and which `git show-ref` is showing you: branch names and remote-tracking names both use a more general mechanism.  This means they have *full* names, which are spelled starting with `refs/heads/` and with `refs/remotes/` respectively.

You can't, with `git branch` or `git checkout -b`, create a *remote-tracking name*.  You can only create a *branch name*.  Your Git will create, update, and destroy *remote-tracking names* based on the *other* Git's branch names!  Remember, each Git is its own Git, so each one has its own branch names.  Your remote-tracking names are just your Git's way of remembering *their* Git's branch names.

Now, you said:

> ... I accidentally created a new branch origin/<name> ...

but as I noted above, you literally *can't* do that.  You *can* create a (local) branch named, say, `origin/ron`, but its full name will be `refs/heads/origin/ron`.<sup>1</sup>  Your `git show-branch` output shows `refs/remotes/origin/ron` which means you *don't* have a branch named `ron`.  That means there's nothing to delete!

Now, if you want `origin/ron` to go away, that's a little trickier.  You need to convince the *other* Git to delete *its* branch named `ron`.  If you use a web GUI to talk to the other Git, that may have its own clicky buttons for creating and deleting branch names in that Git.  Or, you can use your Git, with its `git push`, to send a request to their Git that they delete *their* `ron`, which is pretty straightforward:

```
git push --delete origin ron
```

will do that.

Once they *don't* have a branch named `ron`—a reference whose full name, in *their* Git, is `refs/heads/ron`—you then want to have *your* Git obtain their latest information, and use that to "prune" any left-over *remote-tracking names* that you have, using:

```
git fetch --prune origin
```

That will have your Git call up their Git and get their list of branches (which now won't include their `ron`), then update your remote-tracking names based on their branches (which will delete your `origin/ron`).

---

<sup>1</sup>Don't do it!  It won't break Git—Git knows, because of the `refs/heads/` part, that it's a branch name, not a remote-tracking name—but it's confusing as all heck.  If you did do it by accident, use `git branch -d` to delete it, or `git branch -m` to rename it (m stands for "move" = rename), so that it does not look like a remote-tracking name.